# How can I set the default page for https requests?

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, https, windows-server-2003

We have a website which has a Virtual Directory containing the secure portion of the website.

If users come to `http://www.mydomain.com`, they should get directed to `default.aspx` of the main site, but if they go to `https://www.mydomain.com`, they should go to `default.aspx` of the virtual directory.

The default page for the main site works fine, as does the secure page if I navigate to it using the full name, however I can't figure out how to set the default page for https traffic that doesn't specify a specific page.

1. http://www.mydomain.com - Works
2. https://www.mydomain.com - Page Not Found
3. https://www.mydomain.com/myvirtualdirectory - Page Not Found
4. https://www.mydomain.com/myvirtualdirectory/default.aspx - Works

What do I need to do to make links 2 and 3 load the default page show in 4?

My website is running on IIS 6.0 in Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out my issue. In my case, it turns out the problem was an old URL Rewrite rule I wasn't aware of that was transferring all https traffic that didn't have a file name specified to `index.php`, which of course didn't exist.

I found this out by [viewing the IIS error logs](http://portal.smartertools.com/KB/a154/where-are-my-iis-log-files-stored.aspx), which was telling me the 404 was being caused by `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Overall, this is an anti-pattern as you state the entire behavior of the site changes based on the port. I am not stating definitively you are doing this, but consider the following:

If you are redirecting due to a user needing to see other things, you can make conditional controls that display only when in HTTPS. The same can be done for authenticated and authorized versus not.

If you are redirecting because an HTTP user needs to log in, the more consistent pattern is to have them click a log in button. And, you can force HTTPS at this point without breaking the pattern.

If you really need to redirect for some reason, there are a couple of ways of handling this:

- [In IIS](http://jameskovacs.com/2007/05/09/how-to-autoredirect-to-a-sslsecured-site-in-iis/)
- [HTTP Handlers](http://asp.net.bigresource.com/HttpHandlers-Modules-redirect-a-page-from-http-to-https-using-http-module-begin-request-handler--g8LgmguRQ.html)
- [URL Rewrite](http://forums.iis.net/t/1153050.aspx) - requires the [URL Rewrite bits for IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)

I imagine there are some other ways to solve this.

Comment: Thanks, but your links are about redirecting http traffic to https. I want to simply set the default page for https traffic. For example, I want to know how to set the default page for `https://mydomain.com/somevirtualdirectory`